# How to auto login live account using client id / client secret in c# without enter credentials?

Tags: onedrive, live-sdk

Please help me how to auto login live account using client id / client secret without enter login credentials in c#?

I am developing web application and I don't want to login manually Microsoft account. So this is automatically login progamatically using ClientId or ClientSecret after that I'll upload files on OneDrive.

Comment: Show what you have done, and where you're stuck

Comment: I have coded a method to SignIn using ClientId, ClientSecret, and RedirectUrl. When I execute the code redirect to MS Account Login page for credentials after login succeeded returns on RedirectUrl with AuthCode. It is working fine but I want that without entering credentials it will automatically login on the client side. I am Asp.net MVC with C#.